# Are child safety covers still required on modern outlets?

Tags: circuit-breaker, child-safety

I have a vague memory of either our electrician or home inspector telling us that the outlets in our recently renovated condo do not need those plastic child safety covers in order to be child-proofed because the circuit breakers are in some way better now than when I was a kid. Is there any truth to this? [image]

Comment: I dont believe those silly plug-in child protection covers were ever required by code or law.  They are basically safety theater, so you might find them on receptacles near TSA checkpoints.  Any child with the industry to put something metallic in the hot pin would also have the industry to remove the cover.

Answer (score 3):

Along with arc-fault breakers protecting some areas of the home, "tamper-resistant" outlets are also required. They don't allow insertion into just one slot--both slots must be pressed together as an actual plug would do.

I get the sense that you're asking about protecting little people. I'd either use plugs or install tamper-resistant outlets if I had toddlers, regardless of arc-fault protection.

Comment: +1. And tamper-resistant outlets have gotten better in recent years, as people had trouble inserting an actual plug into them before.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how much help AFCI is for the kid problem, though GFCI is definitely a huge improvement. But good tamper resistant outlets can slow the kids down a bit...

Comment: I hate the tamper resistant outlets , in Oregon all the outlets below 5'6" are now required to be tamper resistant even GFCI'S both inside and out.

Comment: Jiggleitalittleit'llgo.

Comment: @isherwood, lol .... that sounds like a great T-shirt slogan

Comment: yikes; it takes me forever to de-child-safety those things; remind me to stay away from oregon...